# Exibindo uma imagem ao invés de duas usando og:image

Tags: facebook, html-meta-tag

Estou usando `tags` `og:` `Open Graph` para ter um `snippet` personalizado quando o link de meu site for compartilhado,
porem quando colo o link para `compartilhar` me é dado uma opção de imagens para serem inseridas (através de setas de seleção)
porem criei somente uma tag `<meta property="og:image" content="">` era para exibir somente uma imagem (a que eu defini).

Código HTML das tags Open Graph.

```
        <meta property="og:title" content="Titulo site">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Descrição">
        <meta property="og:url" content="url">
        <meta property="og:image" content="imagem">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name">
```

Snippets com duas imagens (eu quero com uma só, a do tio-sam)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Detalhes:**

1. As imagens estão na mesma pasta (e são os únicos arquivos nela).
2. As imagens estão em um `div` e são as únicas imagens imediatamente
   `filhas` desta `div` e são `irmãs`.

**O que já fiz pra tentar resolver**

1. Retirar a imagem indesejada da pasta onde esta a imagem desejada (tio-sam). Não funcionou.
2. Colocar um `/` de fechamento na `tag`. Não funcionou.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o debug do facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: O facebook guarda cache, o debug tem a opção de limpar o cache.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Mas nem era pra ele fazer cache desta imagem porque eu não a especifico hora alguma.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, no debugger esta do jeito mostra como imagem o tio-sam na tag og:image porem no snippet exibe outra imagem.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, Como posso deletar o cache?

Comment: Faz o submit da URL e daí ele vai te mostrar as opções, então aparecem dois botões, o `Fetch new scrape information` limpa o cache. Fiz o teste aqui, e só está aparecendo uma imagem a do tio Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto pode ser cache do facebook. Utilizando a [Ferramenta de Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), você pode limpar o cache clicando no botão <kbd>Fetch new scrape information</kbd>. Para saber qual foi a última vez que as informações da URL foram atualizadas, tem a informação `Time Scraped`

[image: Ilustração - Facebook Debugger]

Comment: Pois também tive ideia que seria isso. Isso limpa sozinho de algum em algum tempo?

Comment: Então @JorgeB. tem uma [resposta em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16352467/3497987) que diz que o cache é limpo quando alguém curte o link e a cada 24h também, diz também que ele leva em consideração as propriedades "Expires" e "Cache-Control" da página. Fiz uns testes e a opção do curtir funcionou, porém tem alguns links meus que estão com cache do dia 23/4.

Comment: Adiciona essa informação a resposta como nota ;)