# Facebook Open Graph do link da postagem do meu site não aparece descrição e thumbnail é pequena

Tags: facebook, blogger, html-meta-tag

Estou a trabalhar no Open Graph de uma plataforma Blogger. Quando publico algo no facebook, a apresentação do conteúdo de um artigo aparece desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando colo o link da postagem do blog no Facebook não fica exatamente como gostaria, quero que a imagem fique maior, com título e descrição da postagem, exatamente assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As tags estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já utilizei o Open Graph Object Debugger.
Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Deves utilizar imagens que são pelo menos `600 x 315` para que a imagem apareça grande como no segundo exemplo mencionado na tua pergunta. Podes postar aqui o link da publicação que estás a tentar partilhar para poder ver o que se está a passar com a descrição?

Comment: Aqui o link http://www.futebolcomblush.com.br/2015/07/crise-no-cariri.html

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67143/8493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que as imagens apareçam grandes como no segundo exemplo mencionado na sua pergunta, utilize imagens que têm pelo menos `1200 x 630` pixels para melhor exibição em dispositivos de alta resolução. O tamanho mínimo requerido para que as imagens apareçam grandes desta maneira, é de `600 x 315` pixels. E o tamanho mínimo requerido para a `og:image` é de `200 x 200`.

> <sub>Podes ler mais sobre o tópico - `og:image` [**aqui neste link**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images)</sub>

No entanto eu reparei que o problema da imagem aparecer pequena foi devido a uma falta de atualização, pois após ter inspecionado o link no [**`Object Debugger`**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) eu vi que a imagem aparece grande após ter atualizado o link com o Object Debugger.

Sobre a descrição não aparecer, experimenta trocar a `og:description` da seguinte maneira.
Troca o código atual:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != ""'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

Para o seguinte:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Ler artigo sobre &quot; + data:blog.pageName + &quot; em &quot; + data:blog.title + &quot;&quot;' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

Basicamente o que isto vai fazer é pegar a `meta description` caso esta exista e exibi-la como `og:description`, mas se não houver uma `meta description` disponível, então o texto `Ler artigo sobre ...` irá ser implementado como `og:description` em vez disso.

### `Meta description` no Blogger

Para activar as `meta description` você tem que ir até:

> `Definições > Preferência de pesquisa > Meta tags > Descrição` Clique em editar.
>   E irá aparecer o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Adicionar `Meta description` a publicações individuais

Simplesmente edite a sua publicação ou página e procure pela opção **Descrição da Pesquisa**, e é aqui que iremos adicionar a descrição de cada página que agora também vai ser exibida como `og:description` para o Facebook.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Chun!  
Eu fiz o que você sugeriu, agora aparece a descrição e a imagem ta grande, só falta ser a descrição da postagem, olha como ficou:  
http://oi59.tinypic.com/a2rsyq.jpg  
Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Oi @DiegoGomes , desculpa faltou mencionar a parte de - "ativar as `meta description` tags". Já atualizei a minha resposta. Ele agora deve funcionar na perfeição =)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado :)    Pensei que já tinha marcado a resposta correta aqui, desculpa

Answer (score 2):

Você não está escrevendo as meta tags do facebook, está? E para a imagem aparecer maior ela deve ter o tamanho 600x315 ou 1200x630.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Lorem ipsum" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="URL_DA_IMAGEM" />
```

Link da documentação: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Oi, essa descrição que devo inserir é a do site, ou da postagem?  
Essa é uma das dúvidas que tenho, porque se for pra escolher uma padrão, todas serão iguais?

Comment: @DiegoGomes a descrição é das postagens, será o que vai aparecer no dialog do facebook. O mesmo para title e image

Comment: Isso que o @KaduAmaral falou. Mas tipo na index do seu site você deixa o título, descrição e imagem do site mesmo. E interna das notícias você deixa com os dados da notícia, etc.